# Reading API - code from Curl to R

Tags: r, rcurl, httr

I am trying to read a json from an authenticated API using R, but not sucessfully.

I have the Curl code and tried to convert it to R using "curlconverter" library and also tried to get it using "httr" library.

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/auth/liga/gurudocartola-com?orderBy=campeonato&page=1' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'x-glb-token: mytoken'
```

I would appreciate a solution to write this code in R.

Comment: You can wrap system calls in the `system()` command. Alternatively you can use a library such as [`curl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/vignettes/intro.html) or [`httr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html) for this kind of task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
library(curlconverter) # devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/curlconverter")

u <- "curl -X GET 'https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/auth/liga/gurudocartola-com?orderBy=campeonato&page=1' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'x-glb-token: mytoken'"

straighten(u) %>% 
  make_req()
```

That makes:

```
httr::VERB(verb = "GET", url = "https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/auth/liga/gurudocartola-com?orderBy=campeonato&page=1", 
           httr::add_headers(`Cache-Control` = "no-cache", 
                             `x-glb-token` = "mytoken"))
```

which very straightforwardly (if one has done *any* research before posting a question) translates to:

```
httr::GET( 
  url = "https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/auth/liga/gurudocartola-com", 
  httr::add_headers(
    `Cache-Control` = "no-cache", 
    `x-glb-token` = "mytoken"
  ),
  query = list(
    `orderBy` = "campeonato",
    `page` = 1L
  )
)
```

The back-ticks are there solely to remind me they are parameters (and, they sometimes contain dashes or other chars which force a back-tick quote).